# How to get data between tags of input field at last

Tags: php, html, curl

This is the following field I want to fetch name of input field :--

```
***<input type="text" class="boxfieldcontent" maxlength="10" value="10 digit mobile number"       
onblur="javascript:FillValueOnBlur('mkhGzaCcqx','10 digit mobile number');" 
onfocus="javascript:FillValueOnFocus('mkhGzaCcqx','10 digit mobile number');" name="mkhGzaCcqx" 
id="mkhGzaCcqx" style="display:none;">***
```

How is it possible ?
Also tell preg_match complete details with example.

I want to fetch only id or name of input field given above.

Comment: what do you want,be precise and dont add unnecessary styling to your questions.Where is your js.What research have you done???
Do you think your question explains all these questions--------NO,it doesnt.Get some help from metaStackoverflow about how to format questions.

Comment: Be a little less confrontational, we all need help sometime and clearly this guy needs a little more than others.

Comment: Please reformat you question so it is a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

For id you should use

```
preg_match('/<input.* id="([^"]+?)"/', $str, $match);
```

where $str is string containing html

For name you should use

```
preg_match('/<input.* name="([^"]+?)"/', $str, $match);
```

`$match[1]` will contain input id or name

Preg match needs at least 2 params we will use 3.

1. Regex pattern to be searched
2. The input string
3. Array of matches that results are returned to.

More you can find in [manual](https://www.php.net/preg_match)